# How to prevent a different JTable row from being selected?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JFrame` window that looks like this:

[image]

Basically, Whatever row from the `JTable` is selected, details will be displayed about in the pane on the right (which is a `JRootPane`).

The root pane contains a few actions that the user can perform, like generating and saving an image from the data it has about the selected item.

While doing this, a glass pane will be displayed over the `Item Details` with a loading spinner and a blurred background.

Currently however the user is still able to select a different row while this is happening.

Is there a way (aside of displaying a glass pane over the table) for me to keep the selected row selected, while also preventing another row from getting selected? Maybe some event listener?

I tried creating a custom `MouseAdapter` with a `mouseClicked` method doing nothing, but that didn't work. And setting `setRowSelectionAllowed` to `FALSE` will deselect the currently selected row.

Comment: Do you want to select only one row in the table?

Comment: No, I want to know how to stop another row from being selected (ie: canceling out a mouse click event or something). I already know how to only have a single row selected.

Comment: Look at SELECTION LISTENER in the JTable

Comment: doesn't look like a `selection listener` will allow me to cancel out the event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the outset, the solution you discarded (covering the JTable with the GlassPane) seems to be a better solution.

That said, you can override `Component#processEvent` and conditionally not call the `super` to ignore all events on your table.

Comment: Hm okay, looks like a glasspane would be the best way to go then

Comment: @xorinzor Check out the [Disabled Glass Pane](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/07/disabled-glass-pane/). It will intercept the mouse and keyboard events.